# Повозки везут. Речевая ошибка?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Ребенок написал в сочинении: "На заднем плане видны повозки, они везут сено". Учитель отметила предложение как речевую ошибку. Она права?

Comment: А учительница не объяснила, в чем именно заключается речевая ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

Здесь нет речевых ошибок, только орфографическая (отсутствие пробела после запятой). Видимо, учительница предпочла бы лаконичное "видны повозки с сеном", но и написанному есть своё обоснование: сначала можно заметить какие-то повозки на дальнем плане, а потом уже разглядеть, что везут они не что-нибудь, а сено - автор вправе вести в таком порядке повествование. То, что "повозки *везут* сено", ничем не хуже, чем "кузнец куёт что-то" - а что он ещё должен делать? Если колёса у повозок исправны, они именно *везут* то, что на них, а не "волочат", "тащат" или "влекут" :)

Comment: Александр, мне кажется, учительница скорей всего имело в виду: "повозки везут".

Comment: Возможно, но эти "проблемные" слова даже разнесены по разным предложениям.

Comment: Да, полностью согласен. Посмотрим, что скажет автор.

Comment: А может быть, правильнее "на них везут сено"?

Comment: Хороший вопрос :)  Если транспортное средство едет (а это трудно оспорить), оно де-факто "везёт" то, что на нём - независимо от наличия внешней тягловой силы или воли (лошадка, везущая хворосту воз, люди, посредством её запряжения перевозящие его же, стоящая за организацией этой перевозки транспортная компания и т.п.) - на эту силу следующего уровня абстракции нет необходимости ссылаться. Аналогично, ракета-носитель "несёт", а не "на ней несут".  Иначе пришлось бы повсеместно "самолёт меня уносит" заменять на "меня уносит/уносят самолётом" и то же самое делать с уносящими и везущими поездами.

Answer (score 1):

Мне не очень нравится оборот "на заднем плане видны". На заднем плане можно находится, быть изображенным, но "быть видным" - это как-то очень витиевато получается.

Если это ошибка, то не знаю как классифицировать, вроде на речевую ошибку не тянет, просто какая-то тяжеловесность речи. Но это максимум, что я могу придумать.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению

Comment: Если "на заднем плане видны" означает "быть видным", а не быть видимым, то, очевидно, что-то надо подправить в вашей витиеватой консерватории. ====== Прочтите ваш Ответ: Мне не очень нравится оборот "на заднем плане видны". На заднем плане можно находится, быть изображенным, но "быть видным" - это как-то очень витиевато получается.===== Это ваш максимум?

Comment: Не принципиально. А насчет консерватории - это не ко мне. Во всяком случае - не с Вами. И кончайте уже на личности переходить, если это "Ваш максимум", то Вас в консерваторию не пустят .

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, повозки сами по себе не могут везти сено.

ВЕЗТИ, кого-что. Перемещать, доставлять в определённом направлении кого-, что-л. с помощью каких-л. средств передвижения.

Поэтому везут лошади и повозку, и сено, а повозка не может везти, это ее везут. А вот поезд возит пассажиров и грузы, так как тяговое устройство входит  его состав.

Comment: Да, лошадь везёт повозку, но повозка, которая в результате этого едет, везёт то, что на ней. Вот первое попавшееся: перевод, правда, но это изданная в Петербурге (т. е. прошедшая корректуру) книга "История чартизма" (1907). " Во главе процессии ехала повозка, запряжённая четырьмя лошадьми и украшенная знамёнами. Эта повозка должна была везти Национальную Юстицию."
https://books.google.ru/books?id=4PD3BQAAQBAJ&hl=ru&hl=ru&pg=PA354&img=1&zoom=3&ots=3yH-GZLrI7&sig=ACfU3U2TeQyXnc43zvkdphcNfLWAciqYHg&w=1280

Comment: P.S. Если набрать гуглом "повозка везла", первый десяток результатов - книги.

Comment: Здесь   "повозка, запряжённая четырьмя лошадьми", то есть  единый тягловый механизм "лошади + повозка". И далее - "эта повозка",  то есть опять же вместе с лошадьми.

Comment: А все повозки так устроены - такой у них тип двигателя, речь не меняется от того, называют его выносным или нет. Дело не в этой конкретной цитате, можно много найти из эпохи повозок. Сенкевич, "Пан Володыёвский" (о повозке, словесно не "запряжённой лошадьми"). Золотая повозка везла Кассеку под балдахином из пурпурного тифтика, за нею шли другие повозки и белые навьюченные сирийские верблюды, также накрытые пурпуром. https://books.google.ru/books?id=5R5hAAAAQBAJ&hl=ru&hl=ru&pg=PT439&img=1&zoom=3&sig=ACfU3U09VnDQEcSGkrl4Wmh8-vMtQJ_b0g&w=1280

Comment: Sergey, в в чем разница между: поезд возит пассажиров и повозки везут сено? вы говорите: "так как тяговое устройство входит его состав''. Так же очевидно, что в состав повозки входят лошади.

Comment: Может быть,  и очевидно, что лошади входят в состав повозки, но ведь речь идет о языковой сочетаемости. Мне кажется, что  в современном языке странно говорить, что повозки ходят или что они возят что-либо. И все-таки лошадки катают детей, а не санки.

Comment: То, что лошадки "катают", просто выражает другое отношение в системе двигатель - водитель - пассажиры (груз): таксист тоже может "катать" или везти пассажиров по городу, а машина, которой он управляет, тоже будет при этом их "везти" - это перемещение людей можно выразить любым выбранным способом. Входимость лошади в повозку или её воля катать не влияют на факт перемещения груза колесным сооружением: оно "едет" (само или за счёт того, что его тянет) и в силу этого "везёт" то, что в нём и на нём.

Answer (score -2):

Повозка, а это не отдельные телега или сани, представляется единицей гужевого транспорта. Поэтому некоторая тавтологичность ошибкой не должна считаться, тем более, что *воз* — от слова *возить*, а не везти.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/5751)

Comment: Примерно так во всех словарях: Пово́зка — транспортное средство, предназначенное для перемещения по твёрдой поверхности грузов или пассажиров с использованием силы мускулов животных или человека. ==== Есть вопросы, обращайтесь.

Comment: Вопросов нет. Буду чистить.

Comment: Прошу в конюшни.